# Indesign: Can I delete images so I can send a smaller file to colleague?

Tags: adobe-indesign

My indesign file is 13 MB; too big to send by email.  Images that are making it so big. Here is my idea: I send my colleague all the necessary images in a library, that we will both have access to.   I remove the images from the indesign file, but leave the links.  What I mean, is that the links will still be in the indesign file, and the links will be looking for the files, but it won't find the files.  When my colleague gets the indesign file, the indesign file will be able to find all the images in the libarary, which he has.  Hence, we can send back and forth a file that should be far less than a MB.

Is this possible?

Comment: If it's too big to send by email then don't send it by email. Upload it to a file sharing site instead, and send the link by email. You can use file sharing services such as the Adobe Cloud, Drop Box, Google Drive, etc.

Comment: Or use a version control like git. Then host it in a version control sharing service like github, bitbucket etc.

Comment: linked images are *not* stored in the file, so not sure what "removing images but leaving the links" even means. If you are "pasting" images in, don't do that

Comment: @Yorik   I mean that the file is very large, so I'm assuming that it is storing the information in the images.   If my file contained only text and formatting instructions, then it would be less than a half MB.

Comment: @Scott  Thanks, the IDML file is what I'm looking for.  If I send this file to my colleague, then he will see the "skeleton" of the document. That is, he will see the text and where the images go, ect.  The IDML is only a half MB, which makes sense.   If I send him all the images at a later point in time, then they will load automatically.   I believe this is a solution.

Comment: Added comment as answer... and addressed image linking. With an IDML file, no one will "see" anything... InDesign can open the IDML markup and *regenerate* the layout. The .idml file is not a "visual" file. To perhaps explain more..... IDML is like looking at HTML markup.. .all text.. compared to looking at an .indd file - i.e. a web page which is the *visual* rendering of the markup text.

Comment: @Scott I insert my images with the "place" command.  Therefore, I am not pasting.  Is that correct?

Comment: > "InDesign only links to external images."   I am getting a bit into semantics here, but I would argue that when I place an image, then Indesign is putting alot more than a simple link into the file.   A link would be less than a hundred character long. A link would just be a file location.  Indesign is putting a lot more data in the file than just a link. Correct?

Comment: Chris, it's a *reference* link.. then **all** the *local* information surrounding that reference... size, location, rotation, color, etc. It's more than a simple link like in HTML.

Comment: @Scott  Judging by the size of my ID file, I believe that this "reference link" also includes a small version of the image.  Maybe it isn't a high quality versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InDesign *only* links to external images, unless as @Yorik points out in comments, you are pasting images into the InDesign file. Which **is** a bad idea.

13mb is really not large at all. Even with only reference links, it's fairly easy to hit 13mb for an INDD file in roughly 20pgs.

Saving as an **[IDML file](https://fileinfo.com/extension/idml)** (InDesign Markup Language) might reduce the file size. An IDML file is merely a *markup data* file that InDesign can read and then regenerate the layout based upon the markup. Unlike an actual .indd layout, the .idml data is typically much smaller in terms of file size. One simply *must* have InDesign to utilize an .idml file.

If an IDML file works, images **won't** typically "automatically" relink. 
But it's easy enough to [relink images to a folder](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/155745/3270)....

Or you can archive the .indd file in something like a [.zip archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)). Which *should* reduce the file size. But there's no telling what any size reduction may be without actually archiving the file. (One *should* be "zipping" InDesign files when emailing them anyway. Sending raw InDesign files through email will often result in file corruption due to common email server virus scanning.)

There are also file transfer services such as [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/), [Hightail](https://www.hightail.com/), [GoogleDrive](https://www.google.com/drive/)... which would allow for larger file transfers and circumvent the 10mb limit found on many email servers.

Comment: If I were your editor, I would ask you to focus you answer on the IDML file.  Your coments about DropBox, Google drive, ect. answer a question that I didn't ask.   The question was not, 'how can I send a bunch of files to somebody'.  The question was, how can reduce the file size to something I can send in an email.

Comment: @Chris the *goal* is to help *anyone* who may come across this question. The actual *question* was... "how can I reduce the file size in order to send an InDesign file to a friend." -- I answered that with *several* options. You may choose to use the IDML format.. others may prefer a zip, or DropBox. `:)`